# Is it possible to show comments retrieved from /// <inerithdoc cref=""/>

Tags: visual-studio, comments

I like intellisense and I think everyone should always add structured comments on classes and methods, I say so because the concept of being "self commenting code" is per se a wrong practice.
How do you draw the line between something that for the creator is obvious but this isn't true for any other developer?
In my company we have a wide range of very useful shared NuGet packages, but most of them have no comments, or at least in the interfaces. This cause the consumer class, using IoC, to blindly use the interfaces loosing completely the comments and therefore the intellisense.
Maybe I don't create the NuGet packages in the right way, but so far the best practice I found, is to add comments in the interfaces and add in the implementing class, the comment: `/// <inerithdoc cref=""/>`.

This helps me share the documentation, parameters and return type descriptions and so on.
Now the inherithdoc, is mostly used for the XML documentation generation, but not really helpful when it comes to access the description from the implementation class.

An example, I have IMyClass with all the nice comments, if I open MyClass which implements IMyClass, I can read through the code but I don't have straight access to the comments and it is very annoying to be forced to jump back and forth to the Interface in order to read them.

So a possible solution would be to copy the comments across Interfaces and implementing Classes, but I hate duplication, and you can easily end up updating the descriptions here but not there.

So my question for the community is, how do you handle this? Is there Any extension that shows me the description maybe as part of the codelens?
Hovering the mouse on the cref attribute, allow me to get the description of the class/interface and methods, but not parameters.

Comment: Are you talking about bringing your interface comments into your classes that implement them?

Comment: Yes, but not literally copying (duplicating) the information into the implementation class. I would like to be able to View it, as hololens information for example.

Comment: What does HoloLens have to do with viewing comments from an interface?

Comment: Lol, sorry I meant CodeLens. I would like to be able to read the documentation without the need of click or over on anything, nor the duplication of the comments as well.
I am looking around, so far I couldn't find anything, I was actually considering to try to create a plugin myself, but that's a long shot.